# Drupal not recognized installation

Tags: drupal-7, wamp

Despite the complete installation of drupal 7.59, when I execute command `drush cc all` this message is displayed : `No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.`, even I have installed a custom module in my site and I can work with my drupal site on `localhost/my_site/` in browser, it's not recognaized as a `Drupal site` !!!
my main problem is that module is installed correctly but sql tables are not created in database and drush clear cache command doesn't help.

any one can help me what is wrong and why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

99% sure that path variable is wrong. Please check https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2014-05-14/drush-no-drupal-site-found-only-drush-cache-was-cleared

I'm not sure which OS you are using. Check path and port for mysql

Comment: but it was ok and I had checked this link before.